# Vue: Best Vuex practice for having a component that relies on Vuex store property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

In this example of a simple component, if the template required a property to render that is going to be Vuex stored data, is it better to read from the property directly like this:

```
<template>
   <div>
      <div>
         {{ this.$store.getters.getProduct.title }}
      </div>
      <div>
         {{ this.$store.getters.getProduct.name }}
      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

**Or set an initial data value to the store value and use that like this:**

```
<template>
   <div>
      <div>
         {{ this.currentProduct.title }}
      </div>
      <div>
         {{ this.currentProduct.name }}
      </div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                currentProduct: this.$store.getters.getProduct
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mapState` of Vuex and spread it in computed property of the component to get the state directly. Considering that you have a `currentProduct` state in your store...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>{{ currentProduct.title }}</div>
    <div>{{ currentProduct.name }}</div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
  ...
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['currentProduct']).
  }
}
</script>
```

Just use getters if you want to transform some data from your state. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: OP is clearly using _getters_ so why suggest `mapState`?

Comment: The title says "best Vuex practice", OP didn't state also that he wants to use `getters`. and FYI, in this case, OP doesn't need to use `getters` as he only outputs the states from the store, he didn't transform any data before he displayed it, so why use `getters`? I would suggest that you read the `Vuex` documentation first before commenting. Anyway, happy coding.

Comment: OP's code ~ `this.$store.getters.getProduct.title`. They haven't shown their store code so there's no way to tell if they're doing anything in the getters but they are certainly using them and not state directly

Comment: I assume that OP didn't transform any data because of this phrase "Or set an initial data value to the store value and use that like this..." You can post your answer though, there's not too much effort with that. Let the OP decide which one is correct, that's what the stackoverflow for.